# Array with objects, increasing/decreasing one of the value in object after click on button

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, shopping-cart

I'm really rookie. I'm working on implementation of shopping cart and I'm stuck on one of the functionality.
After getting products to my cart (from local storage) I would like to manipulate the quantity of each products.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Havana",
    "price": 475,
    "inCart": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Cubana",
    "price": 150,
    "inCart": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Malibu",
    "price": 105,
    "inCart": 3
  }
]


getFromStorage(product);

function getFromStorage() {
    product = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("product"));
    console.log(product);
    product.forEach(({ name, price, inCart }) => {
    cart.innerHTML += `
<div>${name}</div>
<div>${price}</div>
<i class="fas fa-minus-square"></i>
<div class="in-cart">${inCart}</div>
<i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
    `
  })
}
```

After display my cart i would like to use buttons to increase and decrease value of inCart

[image: UI of cart]

I have started to write the code to increase/decrease a value of inCart but I don't know how to get an access to elements. I would like to update this quantity dynamically in local storage.

```
const decrease = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-minus-square");

for (let i = 0; i < decrease.length; i++) {
  decrease[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    product = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("product"));
```

If someone can help me, would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's good to use ID to identify your product. Product object may look like:

```
{
    id: string,
    name: string,
    price: number,
    quantity: number,
}
```

Function getFromStorage seems ok but for better naming I think you should rename product to products, nevertheless it gets 0 parameters but when u invoke it at line 0 you provide one argument.

```
getFromStorage();

function getFromStorage() {
    products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("product"));
    console.log(product);
    products.forEach(({ id, name, price, inCart }) => {
    cart.innerHTML += `
      <div>${name}</div>
      <div>${price}</div>
      <i class="fas fa-minus-square" onClick=`handleQuantityChange(${id},-1)`></i>
      <div class="in-cart">${inCart}</div>
      <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
    `
  })
}
```

Finally function handleQuantityChange which will gets 2 parameters: id of a products and difference. You may in future use this same function but with "1" second parameter to handle increase

```
function handleQuaintityChange(id, diff){
   const product = products.find(prod=>prod.id===id);
   if(!product) return;
   product.quantity+=diff;
   return true
}
```